# "Collection of" or "Collection from"

Tags: grammar

Can anybody tell me, what should be correct *of* or *from*?
I have used *from*, but when I checked in one grammar software it's showing *of*.
I googled about it but not got anything.

> He must be tallying their daily collection **of/from** the vendors, auto drivers or rickshaw pullers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *counting* or *taking*?

If you are counting, then use *of*.

> He must be tallying their daily collection of vendors, auto drivers, and rickshaw pullers.
>
> That collection of apples includes four different varieties.

Ie. this use case implies he is counting the number of vendors, auto drivers, and rickshaw pullers.

If you are taking, then use *from*.

> He must be tallying the daily collection from the vendors, auto drivers, or rickshaw pullers.
>
> He is counting the tips from the collection of tip jars.

Ie. this construction implies he is counting up the fees (or whatever) that were taken from the vendors, auto drivers, or rickshaw pullers.

Make sense?

Comment: thanks how silly of me. Now I got it. In my case it is from